# Is there any difference between Windows/Linux/Mac Tor Browser user?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

On WIndows, Tor browser's user agent includes "Windows". What about Linux and Mac version of Tor browser? Do they share the same value(e.g. Windows' Tor Browser) or they have their own values?

Can anyone share those UserAgent/navigator.platform?

Answer (score 2):

Tor Browser has the same user-agent on all platforms. On Linux and OSX it still has Windows 6.1 in the user-agent string.

In theory Tor Browser should look the same on all platforms, see bullet point 5 of section 3.1 of [The Design and Implementation of the Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#adversary-goals).

> **Fingerprinting/anonymity set reduction**
>
> Fingerprinting (more generally: "anonymity set reduction") is used to attempt to gather identifying information on a particular individual without the use of tracking identifiers. If the dissident's or whistleblower's timezone is available, and they are using a rare build of Firefox for an obscure operating system, and they have a specific display resolution only used on one type of laptop, this can be very useful information for tracking them down, or at least tracking their activities.

Historically there have been some issues that have been convered which could be used to tell them apart, but I'm not currently aware of any methods (although that certainly does not mean that they don't exist). It is certainly not intended that they can be distinguished.